# When image is clicked, toggle all inner images

Tags: jquery

My html looks like:

```
<a href="..." id="a1">
    <img src="..." style="display: block;">
    <img src="..." style="display: none;">
</a>
```

Now when a1 is clicked, I want to toggle all of the images.

I tried:

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
  $(this).find("img").each( function() {
    $(this).toggle();
  });
});
```

but it didn't work.  Does find only get the 1st found element?

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return false` from the click handler otherwise the hyperlink will be followed when clicked.

Also, you do not need the `each`, simple calling `toggle` on `find` will also do the trick.

This works:

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
  $(this).find("img").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/Uk8Uz/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets execute when you click the element #a1 and it will toggle all images that are descendants of the #a1.

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
  $("#a1 img").toggle();
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#a1").click(function() {
  $(this).find("img").toggle();return false;
});
```